# CouchDB Replication Timeout

Tags: node.js, erlang, npm, couchdb

I'm attempting to maintain a follower database of the public npm registry. Everything was working great until replication requests started failing. An attempt to initiate a continuous replication from 'https://skimdb.npmjs.com/registry' to 'registry' produces the following in the logs:

```
    [Tue, 17 Feb 2015 21:13:11 GMT] [error] [<0.22608.57>] {error_report,<0.30.0>,
                           {<0.22608.57>,crash_report,
                            [[{initial_call,
                                  {couch_replicator_httpc_pool,init,
                                      ['Argument__1']}},
                              {pid,<0.22608.57>},
                              {registered_name,[]},
                              {error_info,
                                  {exit,killed,
                                      [{gen_server,terminate,6},
                                       {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3}]}},
                              {ancestors,
                                  [<0.22607.57>,couch_replicator_job_sup,
                                   couch_primary_services,couch_server_sup,
                                   <0.31.0>]},
                              {messages,[{'EXIT',<0.23647.57>,normal}]},
                              {links,[]},
                              {dictionary,[]},
                              {trap_exit,true},
                              {status,running},
                              {heap_size,377},
                              {stack_size,24},
                              {reductions,43883}],
                             []]}}
[Tue, 17 Feb 2015 21:13:11 GMT] [error] [<0.22471.57>] httpd 500 error response:
 {"error":"timeout"}
```

But I can successfully ping skimdb.npmjs.com:

```
PING ec2-54-86-193-198.compute-1.amazonaws.com (54.86.193.198) 56(84) bytes of data.
    64 bytes from ec2-54-86-193-198.compute-1.amazonaws.com (54.86.193.198): icmp_req=1 ttl=62 time=2.87 ms
    64 bytes from ec2-54-86-193-198.compute-1.amazonaws.com (54.86.193.198): icmp_req=2 ttl=62 time=2.65 ms
```

Comment: It seems like a process was killed for some reason. Maybe the daemon was unsuccessfully stopped and somehow it stayed running in a broken state. Did you try to restart the node?

Comment: The error seems to be handled properly. It begins a series of retries, all of which fail, and eventually gives up.